# How to run mmDM (DEX game mounter) Windows application in Wine?

Tags: 12.04, windows, wine

I am trying to run / install mmDM DEX Game mounter (for windows) in 12.04.

Here is a link to the application. (there are two applications, but multiman is for the ps3)

[DEX Game mounter + multiman](http://www.sendspace.com/file/mbhpom)

Trying to run the `.exe` in Wine does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with VirtualBox Windows XP with Virtio drivers. Can't get **ProDG** in Wine to set `app/home` paths for some reason, but it works in VirtualBox.

1. Run **mmDM**.
2. Find path to your game.
3. Convert it to **DEX** with **mmDM**.
4. Use **ProDG** to set path for `app/home` to the folder of the game.

If you are connected to your PS3 with ProDG, most games need release mode to be set in ProDG. PS3 must be rebooted after setting release mode.

Use the `reset` option in ProDG, then if you picked the path to your game folder in `app/home` in ProDG, you will see it show up in `app/home` on the PS3.

Google for a ProDG, mmDM, DEX compatibility list for per game instructions.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the file with WinRAR for Wine, then install VB runtime for Wine, then it will start but, it can't figure out paths on Unix. I tried symb linking backup to Wine folder but it didn't help. However, `prodg` and `mmdm` does startup on 12.04 Wine.